# How to secure websocket connections internally using cognito AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, amazon-cognito

I have a very particular problem here and I lack the understanding of the AWS resources we can use to achieve results . I would like to use cognito with identity pools that work with custom login to generate aws credentials ( This part has been achieved according to the diagram below ) [image]

I have an application that has two websockets connections and currently there is no authentication in place before a connection is established and I would like to know can we use the same tokens generated from cognito as a method to verify calls landing before the websocket connections and establish a connection or is there a known way to secure websockets connections without using the build web socket API from amazon to authenticate the calls that land to our websockets without causing much latency in establishing the connection